# A Quadratic Problem (which looks very simple)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

This arises as a part of my work.

\begin{align}
\min_{x^{H}x=1}~&x^{H}A_1x \\
\text{subject to}~&x^{H}A_2x=0
\end{align}

where $A_1, A_2$ are $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices and $x$ is a unit norm complex vector to be found. Any recommendations on a iterative algorithm to solve this is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the same question in MO, I got an answer, and I am providing the link here.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114147/a-certain-type-of-quadratic-problem

Answer (score 0):

Write $x=u+iv$ and $A_j=H_j+iK_j$ ($H_j$ is real symmetric and $K_j$ is skew-symmetric), then your minimisation problem can be rewritten as a (perhaps nonconvex) QCQP:
\begin{align}
\textrm{minimize}
& (u^T,v^T)\begin{pmatrix}H_1&-K_1\\ K_1&H_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}\\
\textrm{subject to}
& (u^T,v^T)\begin{pmatrix}H_2&-K_2\\ K_2&H_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}=0,\\
&\|(u^T,v^T)\|^2=1.
\end{align}
As I know very little optimisation theory, I am not sure how easy it is to solve the above problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this is a very well known technique of converting a complex quadratic problem into a real one. In fact, every complex quadratic problem can be converted in this manner. But it doesn't help more than that :(:(

Comment: @dineshdileep Nevermind, but what I really mean is this: since your problem is equivalent to a (perhaps nonconvex) QCQP, and nonconvex QCQP in general, if I understand correctly, are difficult problems, I think your seemingly simple problem is actually nothing simple at all.